# How to convert python async code using websockets library to use websocket-client library (for proxy)

Tags: python, websocket, proxy, bots, webex

I'm attempting to set up a Webex bot for my team and I've done my best to follow along with every solution that seems viable, but everything gets stuck at a particular stumbling block; it has to work with our company's proxy.

I've been focusing on [this bot by fbradyirl](https://github.com/fbradyirl/webex_bot), as it seems like it will be the best for us to work with once we get it working. The problem is, it uses the [Python Websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library, which doesn't support using a proxy. I've looked into alternative libraries and found this [Websocket-Client](https://websocket-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) that seems like a good alternative which supports proxy. I've managed to find the specific part of the bot library which I need to change through some testing, but I'm not sure how to create code that performs the same function using Websocket-Client instead of Websockets. Here's the specific code in question [line 154]:(https://github.com/fbradyirl/webex_bot/blob/main/webex_bot/websockets/webex_websocket_client.py)

```
@backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo, websockets.ConnectionClosedError)
@backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo, websockets.ConnectionClosedOK)
@backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo, websockets.ConnectionClosed)
@backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo, socket.gaierror)
async def _connect_and_listen():
    ws_url = self.device_info['webSocketUrl']
    logger.info(f"Opening websocket connection to {ws_url}")
    async with websockets.connect(ws_url, ssl=ssl_context) as _websocket:
        self.websocket = _websocket
        logger.info("WebSocket Opened.")
        msg = {'id': str(uuid.uuid4()),
               'type': 'authorization',
               'data': {'token': 'Bearer ' + self.access_token}}
        await self.websocket.send(json.dumps(msg))

        while True:
           await _websocket_recv()

try:
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(_connect_and_listen())
except Exception as runException:
    logger.error(f"runException: {runException}")
    if self._get_device_info(check_existing=False) is None:
        logger.error('could not create device info')
        raise Exception("No WDM device info")
    # trigger re-connect
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(_connect_and_listen())
```

How can I convert the code in _connect_and_listen to use websocket-client instead of websockets? Or is there some other way I can make the Webex bot work with the proxy?